# Incorporating an image in the rich-ui treeview

Tags: grails, treeview, rich-ui

I am using the Rich-UI plugin treeview feature in a Grails application.  I have it working but was trying to see how to incorporate a pdf icon/image in the treeview to identify to the user they can launch a pdf from the link.  Can someone explain to me how to place an image in the treeview?  Any help with file names, etc would be greatly appreciated.